# Coq - fold and maps on record types

Tags: record, fold, coq

I had previously posted problems like the following, but have not yet found a solution. I am having a store (mapping) from a record type (with five members) to a string value. A fold with a function guarding on the three elements of the record and returns a mapping (string to string). I need to solve some lemmas like **gsc_MapsTo_iff_right** below.

The code may contain some awkward syntax (for example fold) as I am not expert of Coq. Sorry for that.

Thank you for your help.

Wilayat

```
Require String.  

Record c_id : Type := build_c_id {
  c_id_d : String.string;
  c_id_p : String.string;    
  c_id_s : bool; 
  c_id_h : bool; 
  c_id_k : String.string   
}.


Definition skey := String.string.   
Definition st (elt:Type) := list (String.string * elt).
Variable elt : Type. 

Parameter Sadd : skey -> String.string -> st String.string -> st String.string.
Parameter SMapsTo : skey -> String.string -> st String.string -> Prop.

Definition ckey := c_id. 
Definition ct (e:Type) := list (ckey * elt).
Implicit Type cm: ct elt.  


Parameter Cadd : ckey -> String.string -> ct String.string -> st String.string.
Parameter CMapsTo : ckey -> String.string -> ct String.string -> Prop.


Parameter elements : ct String.string -> list (ckey*String.string).

Fixpoint rec_fold {A : Type} (f: ckey -> String.string -> A -> A) (l : list (ckey * String.string)) (b: A) : A :=
 match l with
 | nil => b
 | cons (k, v) t => f k v (rec_fold f t b)
 end.

Fixpoint fold {A: Type} (f: ckey -> String.string -> A -> A)
                   (cm: ct String.string) (b:A) : A := 
 rec_fold f (elements cm) b. 

Parameter empty : st String.string.

Axiom str_dec : forall a b : String.string, {a = b} + {a <> b}.
Definition str_eqdec (a b: String.string):bool :=
 if str_dec a b then true else false. 

Notation "x =?= y" := (str_eqdec x y) (at level 30).

Definition andb (b1 b2:bool) : bool := if b1 then b2 else false.
Notation "x & y" := (andb x y) (at level 40).


Definition get_sc (d p: String.string) (ckm: ct String.string)  
 : st String.string := 
       fold
         (fun cki v zm => if d =?= cki.(c_id_d) & 
                             p =?= cki.(c_id_p) &
                             (negb (cki.(c_id_s)))
                           then Sadd cki.(c_id_k) v zm
                          else zm ) 
          ckm 
         empty. 


Lemma gsc_MapsTo_iff_right:
  forall p d zk zv zh cm,
  CMapsTo (build_c_id d p false zh zk) zv cm ->
  SMapsTo zk zv (get_sc d p cm).
Proof. 
 Admitted.
```

Comment: I don't understand, do you assume some axioms regarding CMapsTo and SMapsTo? Could you list them?

Comment: @Ptival In my original code, it assumes all the definitions/Axioms for (add, MapsTo, fold etc) from FSetWeakList.Make, but I need them with `key` and `elt` to be `c_id` and `String.string` for CMapsTo/CAdd and `String.string`, `String.string` for SMapsTo/SAdd. I did't know to instantiate MapsTo, add and fold directly from the library with my types.

Comment: I found that the lemma in current form does not hold. A property of the following form needs to be added: `Definition c_valid (cm: ct String.string): Prop := 
forall cki cki' zv, 
CMapsTo cki zv cm ->
CMapsTo cki' zv cm ->
cki.(c_id_d) = cki'.(c_id_d) ->
cki.(c_id_p) = cki'.(c_id_p) ->
cki.(c_id_k) = cki'.(c_id_k) ->
(cki.(c_id_s) = cki'.(c_id_s) /\ 
cki.(c_id_h) = cki'.(c_id_h) ).


Lemma get_site_cookies_MapsTo_iff:
  forall prot p d zk zv cm,
  c_valid cm ->
  SMapsTo zk zv (get_site_cookies prot d p cm) <-> 
  (exists zs, exists zh, CMapsTo (build_c_id d p zs zh zk) zv cm).
Proof. `